# Rendering a mesh only if behind another mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, stencil-buffer

I'm trying to render a mesh ("content mesh") (with depth testing) only when it is behind another mesh ("window mesh").

The first solution would be to use a stencil buffer to only write where the "window mesh" has been written.

My issue is that the "content mesh" can be in front of the "window mesh", and I want to discard the fragments in this case (only visible if behind).

I can simply save the depth coordinates of the "window mesh" in a texture, and discard fragments of the "content mesh" using that information.

However, this implies a texture look-up and the use of 16 bit floating point numbers for the custom deph-test.

Is there another way to do this ?

PS : [How to render a mesh behind another mesh, like a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801153/how-to-render-a-mesh-behind-another-mesh-like-a-mask) This thread almost got me the solution but in my case I don't want to render at all the "content mesh" when it is in front of the "window mesh".

Comment: When your content mesh is depth-sorted, do you even need a depth-buffer when rendering it? You could render with depthtesting set to GL_GREATER, then only parts behind the window will get rendered.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I actually meant I need to use standard GL_LESS depth-testing when rendering the content mesh.

Comment: I would still go for STENCIL ... what is wrong with it exactly? its not clear from your description can you show us a screenshot with description what is wrong with it?

Comment: I didn't figure out a solution involving stencil buffer. But I agree it would be easier/faster... In the example I mentioned, there is no depth testing when drawing the character behind the wall (it is a plain color). I would like to draw a mesh (with depth testing enabled) but only if it is behind a wall. 
In fact, this very close to this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336092/in-opengl-how-can-i-depth-test-between-two-depth-buffers
I hope it is clear(er)

Comment: @Spektre  I've implemented the pseudo solution with a texture and it works fine, I have another z fighting issue but only between triangle from the content mesh, it is something else.
So, I could close this thread, but I findthe problem interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a texture to store the depth, and used it to discard fragment that are closer than this depth.
It works fine. I'm satisfied enough with that.